# How to I change my script so the hostname's IP checks the range of the scope rather than if it matches the scopeID?

Tags: function, powershell, range, ip-address, dhcp

I want to find which scope range the hostname's IP is in by using the data from DHCP. Once I find the right scope range, output the scopes name in my PScustomObject

**Here I pull the data I need from DHCP**

```
$DHServers = Get-DhcpServerInDC
foreach ($Server in $DHServers)
{

$scopes = Get-DHCPServerv4Scope -ComputerName $Server.DnsName | Select-Object Name, ScopeID, StartRange, EndRange 

   ForEach ($Address in $scopes) 
   {
   $Address | Export-Csv "C:\script\Results\ServerScopes.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
   }
}
```

**Here I import the hostname, then get it's IP and details.**

```
$list = Get-Content C:\script\HostNames.txt 

$Output = foreach ($hostname in $list) 
{
  if (test-connection -count 1 -computername $hostname -quiet)  
    {
        $System = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $hostname | Select-Object -Property Name,Model 
        $BIOS = Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $hostname | Select-Object -Property SerialNumber
        $User = get-childitem "\\$hostname\c$\Users" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1
        $mac = invoke-command -computername $hostname {(gwmi -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration).MacAddress | select -first 1}
        $IpV = (test-connection -ComputerName $hostname -count 1 | select -expandproperty IPV4Address).IPaddresstostring

        [PSCustomObject]@{ #Rename varibles in data pull for output file
        ComputerName = $hostname
        Model = $System.Model
        SerialNumber = $BIOS.SerialNumber
        LastUser = $User
        MacAddress = $mac
        IpAddress = $Ip
        NameOfScopeHostIsIn = ??????????
       
        } 
    }
  
    else #statement if hostname is not online
    { 

$Output
$Output | Export-Csv -Path C:\script\Result.csv -No
```

**How can I get the Scope name the host is in, after checking the range?**

Comment: It's not clear to me what help you're asking for. Is it the first function? Can you please limit the post to one specific question, and remove any code that doesn't pertain to this question?

Comment: Thank for the reply. I reformatted my question to hopefully be more concise and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple points to remember:

1. Good code is self-documenting. A comment should tell you what a *group of commands* does, or *why*. It's redundant to comment "getting names from csv" and then write `$computerNames = Import-Csv`, because the line of code makes it just as clear what you're doing.
2. Keep in mind that you can also get the scope of a computer from DHCP by matching against the host name. Try this: `foreach ($scope in $scopes) { if($scope | Get-DhcpServerV4Lease -ComputerName $server | Where-Object HostName -like "$hostName*") { return $scope } }`

```
function Test-IPIsInRange {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    # allow parameters to be piped in
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]$IPAddress,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]$StartRange,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 2, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [System.Net.IPAddress]$EndRange
    )
    # begin defines initialization work for a pipeline-enabled function (has ValueFromPipeline... in
    # any parameter attribute). This scriptblock is run once at the beginning of the function.
    begin {
        # define a helper function to convert an IP address to a numeric value
        function Convert-IPv4ToNumber {
            [CmdletBinding()]
            param(
                [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
                [System.Net.IPAddress]$IPAddress
            )
            process {
                $bytes = $IPAddress.GetAddressBytes()
                [long]$addressNumber = 0
                [long]$factor = 1;
                for($i = $bytes.Length; $i -gt 0; $i--) {
                    $addressNumber += $bytes[$i - 1] * $factor
                    $factor *= 256
                }
                return $addressNumber
            }
        }
    }
    # accepting piped parameters means we have to put the main function logic in process{}
    # This script block is run once for each item piped into the function.
    process {
        # get numeric values of the IP addresses
        $RangeMin = $StartRange | Convert-IPv4ToNumber
        $RangeMax = $EndRange | Convert-IPv4ToNumber
        $Value = $IPAddress | Convert-IPv4ToNumber
        # return whether the address is within the given range
        return ($RangeMin -le $Value -and $Value -le $RangeMax)
    }
}

$DHServers = Get-DhcpServerInDC
foreach ($Server in $DHServers)
{
$scopes = Get-DHCPServerv4Scope -ComputerName $Server.DnsName | Select-Object Name, ScopeID, StartRange, EndRange
# -> note that this line will add scopes repeatedly to the file even if they are already defined
# -> it would be better IMO to import the script, merge the current values, and export it.
    $Scopes | Export-Csv "C:\script\Results\ServerScopes.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
# -> also, no reason to enumerate and append individually if we're piping
# -> the data into the Export-Csv command with the '|' symbol
 }

$hostnames = Get-Content C:\script\HostNames.txt

$Output = foreach ($hostname in $hostnames)
{
# -> It's better to run your commands all in a single script sent to the computer,
# -> especially since you're using invoke-command at all. (If all commands were
# -> `get-wmiobject -computername $hostname` I could see a reason not to).
    try {
        $InvokeCommandParams = @{
            ErrorAction = 'Stop' # set ErrorAction to Stop to allow an error to trigger the catch block
            ComputerName = $hostname
            ScriptBlock = {
# -> Ignore all errors once we're remoted into the computer. 
# -> This prevents an error from tricking the script into thinking the computer is offline.
                trap {continue}
# -> Consider using Get-CimInstance instead of Get-WmiObject. It's basically the modern version of the same command.
                $Network = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object IPAddress -ne $null
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                    Model = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Model
                    SerialNumber = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
                    LastUser = Get-ChildItem "C:\users" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name
                    MacAddress = $Network.MacAddress
# -> I include the following line to select the IPv4 address, otherwise you'll get IPv4 and IPv6.
# -> I don't know enough about IP addresses to know if this is a bad way to do it.
                    IPAddress = $Network.IPAddress | Where-Object { ([ipaddress]$_).AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' }
                }
            }
        }
# -> Splatting can be used to pair parameter names from keys, and values from the values of a hashtable.
# -> It's prettier :)
        $retrieved = Invoke-Command @InvokeCommandParams
        
        $LocationMember = @{
            MemberType  = 'NoteProperty'
            Name        = 'Location'
            Value       = $scopes | Where-Object {$_ | Test-IPIsInRange -IPAddress $retrieved.IPAddress } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
            PassThru    = $true
        }
        $retrieved | Add-Member @LocationMember
    }
# -> If the remote command fails, we know the computer's not online (or at last can't be reached)
    catch {
# -> I'd recommend using Write-Error or pretty much anything but Write-Host in most cases,
# -> but at least try using this instead of the string concatenation that was being used.
        Write-Host "$hostname Is not online, can't pull data for offline assets. $hostname was not added to the output file." -BackgroundColor DarkRed
    }
}
# -> because Invoke-Command returns extra details, we'll narrow our selection
# -> before adding it to the CSV file.
$Properties = @('ComputerName', 'Model', 'SerialNumber', 'Location', 'LastUser', 'MacAddress', 'IPAddress')
$Output | Select-Object $Properties
$Output | Select-Object $Properties | Export-Csv -Path C:\script\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

And I see you updated the question as I was writing this, so I'll check if anything has changed...

Comment: Thank you for the advice and all the comments in the code, I can't thank you enough how helpful this information is as learn PowerShell. It seems the second bit of advice would be the much more simple  option. Again thank you so very much for all the comments in the code you provided, most useful thing  stuff I have gotten since I have started learning Powershell.